# Обратиться к селектору из настроек

Tags: jquery

Допустим, есть скрипт, который инициализируется путём обращения к селектору.

```
$('.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: function() {
        return ('//autocomplete.travelpayouts.com/jravia?locale=ru&with_countries=false&q=' + $(this).val());
});
```

В ней есть настройка `serviceUrl`, в котором функция возвращает ссылку. Но чтобы сгенерировать ссылку, нужно найти значение `.autocomplete`, однако, `$(this)` в теле `serviceUrl` указывает на функцию `serviceUrl`, а не на сам селектор. Так вот, как можно обратиться к `.autocomplete` из тела функции `serviceUrl`?

Comment: "`$(this)` в теле `serviceUrl` указывает на функцию `serviceUrl`" - Вы ошибаетесь, добавьте `console.log(this);` перед `return ...;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему так можно:

```
$('.autocomplete').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: function() {
        return ('//autocomplete.travelpayouts.com/jravia?locale=ru&with_countries=false&q=' + $this.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: А если на странице несколько объектов с классом `.autocomplete`?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, чуть сменил ответ. Так?